# Loop through pivotitems of a pivotfield value in c#

Tags: c#, excel

I have pivot field named `pv4_na2`. I want to loop through all the `PivotItems` in `pv4_na2`, but my `foreach` loop is not working.

The compile error given is

> Can't operate on variable of type
> Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.PivotItem because it does not contain
> public definition of get enumerator

Can anyone give me a solution for this? I need to loop through every Item for visibility.

---

**Code**

```
int D = 0;
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.PivotItem pvt in (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.PivotField)pv4_na2)
 {
   if (pvt.Value == "NA")
   {
       pvt.Visible = true;
       D = 1;
   }
 }
```

It is showing error in foreach loop.

Comment: Actually what is the type of `pv4_na2`

Comment: pv4_na2 is pivot field

Comment: Thank you so much guys ..I got the solution.. the foreach loop will be like

foreach (Excel.PivotItem pvt in worksheet_na2.PivotTables("ICDe Not Avaliable For Stage 2").PivotFields("Stage 2 Status").PivotItems)
                        {
if (pvt.Value == "NA")
                            {
                                pvt.Visible = true;
                                D = 1;
                            }
}

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.PivotField is not an enumerable type and therefore cannot be used in a foreach loop.

Perhaps you are looking for pv4_na2.PivotItems() method which returns a collection of PivotItem as per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.pivotfield.pivotitems.aspx

Answer (score 1):

`pv4_na2` is a `PivotField` and the field contains `PivotItems`. So you need to access it as `pv4_na2.PivotItems` in your `foreach`. See example below.

---

First off, let us make our life easier by setting up an alias at the top of file named `Excel` as

```
 using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

Then we can define the items with the shorter alias as such:

```
Excel.PivotField pivotField = {However you set it};

foreach (Excel.PivotItem item in pivotField.PivotItems())
{
   if (item.Name == itemValue)
        ...
}
```